# Mininet hosts not pinging mininet VM IP

Tags: networking

I have a simple topology with a switch and 2 hosts.

The hosts h1 and h2 can ping each other fine. I have given IPs of 192.168.1.17 and 18 respectively to host 1 and 2.

The mininet IP is 192.168.1.16. I have also set this to be the default gateway for hosts.

I am still unable to ping hosts from mininet and vice versa.

Note that mininet VM IP is pingable from host OS as well as from my other VMs. What am I missing? please help

The python code is:

```py
from mininet.topo import Topo

class MyTopo( Topo ):
    "Simple topology example."

    def build( self ):
        "Create custom topo."

        # Add hosts and switches
        switch = self.addSwitch('s1')
        host1 = self.addHost('h1')
        host2 = self.addHost('h2')

        # Add links
        self.addLink(host1, switch)
        self.addLink(host2, switch)


topos = { 'mytopo': ( lambda: MyTopo() ) }
```

switch is also unable to ping the hosts. what exactly i need to do

Comment: Please update the question to include the code necessary to reproduce this topology and network configuration.

Comment: i have added the code. mininet hosts ping each other fine (10.0.0.1 subnet). The mininet VM and host OS and other VMs on 192.168.1.X subnet ccan ping each other fine. DO i need to change IPs of hosts or is there another way

Answer (score 0):

I have a mininet virtual machine running with the following network configuration:

```
mininet@mininet-vm:~/shoaib$ ip addr
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:b5:66:16 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.170/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 2822sec preferred_lft 2822sec
```

If I start with this in `topo.py`:

```py
from mininet.topo import Topo

class MyTopo( Topo ):
    "Simple topology example."

    def build( self ):
        "Create custom topo."

        # Add hosts and switches
        switch = self.addSwitch('s1')
        host1 = self.addHost('h1', ip='192.168.37.17/24')
        host2 = self.addHost('h2', ip='192.168.37.18/24')

        # Add links
        self.addLink(host1, switch)
        self.addLink(host2, switch)


topos = { 'mytopo': ( lambda: MyTopo() ) }
```

And this in `routes.mn`:

```
h1 ip route add default via 192.168.37.16
h2 ip route add default via 192.168.37.16
```

And then I boot the topology and assign routes:

```
mininet@mininet-vm:~/shoaib$ sudo -E mn --custom topo.py --topo mytopo
*** Creating network
*** Adding controller
*** Adding hosts:
h1 h2
*** Adding switches:
s1
*** Adding links:
(h1, s1) (h2, s1)
*** Configuring hosts
h1 h2
*** Starting controller
c0
*** Starting 1 switches
s1 ...
*** Starting CLI:
mininet>
```

And assign routes:

```
mininet> source routes.mn
mininet>
```

Then we see that mininet has created on the host an OpenVswitch bridge configured like this:

```
mininet> sh ip addr show s1
38: s1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1e:49:17:d6:02:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

At this point, we notice two things about interface `s1`:

1. The link is not up, and
2. It does not have an address.

Let's give it the address we assigned for our default route and bring up the link:

```
mininet> sh ip addr add 192.168.37.16/24 dev s1
mininet> sh ip link set s1 up
```

Which gets us:

```
mininet> sh ip addr show s1
38: s1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1e:49:17:d6:02:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.37.16/24 scope global s1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

At this point, hosts h1 and h2 are able to ping the mininet host using the gateway address:

```
mininet> h1 ping -c 1 192.168.37.16
PING 192.168.37.16 (192.168.37.16) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.37.16: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.10 ms

--- 192.168.37.16 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.097/1.097/1.097/0.000 ms
```

And also the primary host address:

```
mininet> h1 ping -c 1 192.168.122.170
PING 192.168.122.170 (192.168.122.170) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.122.170: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.547 ms

--- 192.168.122.170 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.547/0.547/0.547/0.000 ms
```

But they **cannot** reach any addresses beyond the mininet host:

```
mininet> h1 ping -c 1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

And this is because these packets will be discarded by the gateway on the local network. If we want this to work, the simplest solution is to add a masquerade rule to the netfilter configuration on our mininet host:

```
mininet> sh iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.37.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

And now we have access to outside hosts:

```
mininet> h1 ping -c 1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=10.6 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.639/10.639/10.639/0.000 ms
```

---

If we put all of the above commands into `setup.mn`:

```
h1 ip route add default via 192.168.37.16
h2 ip route add default via 192.168.37.16
sh ip addr add 192.168.37.16/24 dev s1
sh ip link set s1 up
sh iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.37.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Then this simplifies to:

```
$ sudo mn --custom topo.py --topo mytopo
mininet> source setup.mn
```

### Notes

- It is important that the address range we use for the mininet hosts does not conflict with either the address range used by the mininet virtual machine **or** other local networks.
- I am using the address range `192.168.37.0/24` for the mininet hosts because `192.168.1.0/24` is already in use by my local (physical) network.
- `ping` isn't really a great diagnostic tool, especially for remote hosts. It's possible that `ping` will fail even when you can otherwise establish a successful connection. We don't need to worry about that behavior in this example, but it's worth keeping in mind.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed reply, really appreciated. I have managed to reach mininet VM IP with your guidance. But apart from the mininet VM with IP (192.168.1.16) I am still unable to access other machines and host OS on (192.168.1.0/24 subnet) or access internet on mininet hosts.

Comment: It sounds like you missed one of my bullet points, "It is important that the address range we use for the mininet hosts does not conflict with either the address range used by the mininet virtual machine or other local networks."

Comment: I did follow the steps correctly. Mininet hosts and s1 on same interface (192.168.37.X) while the VMs and host OS are on subnet 192.168.1.0

Comment: My purpose is to add the hosts h1 and h2 to domain on AD VM (WIndows Server 2012 R2) which is on same subnet as mininet VM.

Comment: I got this issue resolved by simply using --nat option when executing the topology command. For other way reachability a route is needed on other VM to reach mininet hosts.